# How Latin squares remove variation in experiment design? (2-way blocking)

Tags: statistics, combinatorial-designs, latin-square

I read that latin squares are used to design of experiments when there are 2 sources of nuisance (factors). In that setting, every treatment appears exactly once in each row (factor 1) and column (factor 2). While I think I understand why it is important, I would like to get an explanation with a specific example.
My understanding is that it allows to clearly identify a source of any influence, e.g. if one of the factors influences the treatments, it will be shown clearly irrespective of the other factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from an older edition of Ott & Longnecker: *Statistical Methods and Data Analysis.* I suppose data are fake, but I believe the example suffices to answer your question. (Printouts are from Minitab statistical
software, but are generic in format.)

Suppose an oil company tested four different blends of gasoline for fuel efficiency according to a Latin square design in order to control for the effects of four different drivers and four different models of car. The data are given in the printout below.

Obs    MPG  Driver  Model  Blend

```
 1   15.5       1      1      4
 2   33.9       1      2      2
 3   13.2       1      3      3
 4   29.1       1      4      1
 5   16.3       2      1      2
 6   26.6       2      2      3
 7   19.4       2      3      1
 8   22.8       2      4      4
 9   10.8       3      1      3
10   31.1       3      2      1
11   17.1       3      3      4
12   30.3       3      4      2
13   14.7       4      1      1
14   34.0       4      2      4
15   19.7       4      3      2
16   21.6       4      4      3
```

The ANOVA Table is as follows:

```
Analysis of Variance for MPG     

 Source     DF     Seq SS     Adj SS     Adj MS       F      P
 Driver      3      5.897      5.897      1.966    0.50  0.699
 Model       3    736.912    736.912    245.637   61.90  0.000
 Blend       3    108.982    108.982     36.327    9.15  0.012
 Error       6     23.809     23.809      3.968
 Total      15    875.599
```

This model is othogonal so that SS's for Driver, Model, Blend, and Error
are independent random variables. Thus 'Seq SS' and 'Adj SS' are the same.
F-tests are exact.

> From the point of view of the oil company, the Blend effect is the crucial
>   one. Drivers, and Models of cars are introduced to explain variability
>   If 'Model' had been omitted from the model, then (roughly speaking) 
>   SS Model would be added to SS Error, making SS Error much larger. This would
>   decrease the F-statistic for Blend, and increase the P-value. (This is a
>   now a *block design* in which Blend is the 'main' effect, and Drivers 
>   are blocks.)

If 'Driver' had also been omitted, and we had picked car models and drivers
for each observation at random, we might have gotten an ANOVA table like the
one below, in which it is not possible to see any difference among blends.
(Of course, we will never know, because this hypothetical completely randomized design was not used to obtain our observations.)

```
SOURCE     DF        SS        MS        F        p
Blend       3     109.0      36.3     0.57    0.646
ERROR      12     766.6      63.9
TOTAL      15     875.6
```

A design in which we control for some possible sources of variablility (such as car models and drivers) may
decrease MS(Error) so that the power for detecting differences among the
levels of the main effect, if there are any differences to be detected.

---

*Notes:* (a) Block designs are widely used. It is often easy enough to identify one 
likely major source of variability and make it a block. If there are four
levels of the main effect, then there may be almost any desired number
of levels of the block effect.

(b) By contrast Latin Squares are used less often because of the considerable
constraints of such a design. If there are $k$ levels of the main effect,
then there must also be exactly $k$ levels of the two "blocking" effects.
In practice, it may be difficult to schedule the taking of observations so that each one
is taken with the appropriate levels of each factor.

(c) For certain values of $k$ it may even be possible to use a *Greco-Latin square,*
in which one designates levels of second and third blocking effects
by using Greek and Latin letters, respectively, in a $k \times k$ data table.

(d) *Partially balanced incomplete block designs* offer some flexibility
in the numbers of blocking effects and their levels. Some books on the
design of experiments include tables showing the structures and models
of such designs. Generally, the rows of the ANOVA table for such models
are *not* independent, so it is necessary to use adjusted values of SS's
and MS's to get approximate F-tests. An advantage of Latin square designs
is that they are orthogonal so that exact F-tests are possible.

Comment: What does it mean that the model is orthogonal? There is a vector representation of some kind?

Comment: Your answer is indeed detailed but I am not a statistician and I would appreciate a simple explanation regarding to what exactly means the "averaging out" the variables using latin square. Does it mean I can identifiy the source of variability easily?

Comment: "Orthogonal" does arise from linear algebra (vectors, matrices, etc.). [Simplified version is "perpendicular" in $(x,y)$ plane where the axes are perpendicular.] Standard ANOVA assumes normal data, for which 'orthogonal' and 'independent' are essentially the same. For a true F-test, num and denom of the F-stat must be indep random variables.

Comment: I would not say Latin sq design mainly 'averages out' variability. Main idea is to decrease variability of denom of F. In Latin sq ANOVA table, F-test for Blend is $F\approx 2/4 = 0.5$ (ndf=3, ddf=6; signif); In 2nd table it's  $F\approx 36/54 =0.6$ (ndf=3,ddf=12; not signif). Main distinction btw signif and not signif is the smaller denom, and partly it's the larger denom df. Maybe best to focus on Latin sq as _decreasing_ MS(Err) in denom because some 'variability' is moved to Driver and Model lines of table ('out of the way' for testing signif of Blend).. But the denom df is also involved.